# Using CheckboxTree inside Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm having problem when using react-checkbox-tree inside . After i input value in my text field, and then i click one of the checkbox, my text field will be resetted to the first state.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={this.state}
  enableReinitialize
  {props=> (
    <Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
    <Input
      className="form-control-sm"
      type="text"
      name="groupName"
      id="groupName"
      placeholder=""
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      onBlur={props.handleBlur}
      value={props.values.groupName}
      invalid={
        props.errors.groupName != "" &&
        props.errors.groupName != null
      }
      valid={
        props.values.groupName != "" &&
        props.errors.groupName == null
      }
        />

      <CheckboxTree
        nodes={this.state.nodes}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        expanded={this.state.expanded}
        onCheck={checked => this.onChecked(checked)}
        onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
      />
/>
```

the onChecked function code :

```
onChecked = checked => {
  this.setState({
    checked
 });
}
```

Am i have to change this onCheck function call ? If yes, how can i chain it with Formik function ?

`onCheck={checked => this.onChecked(checked)}`

Comment: You're using enableReinitialize property. It should reset the form if initialValues changes (using deep equality). https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/withFormik#enablereinitialize-boolean

Comment: hi @fetchenko yes i use the enableReinitialize, because i use that form for edit mode too (beside for adding new record). If i don't use enableReinitialize then i can't load data for edit purpose.. Please share a tutorial / example that like my case.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckboxTree
  nodes={props.values.nodes}
  checked={props.values.checked}
  expanded={props.values.expanded}
  onCheck={checked => props.setFieldValue('checked', checked) }
  onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
/>
```

Now the checkbox can work as expected.. I changed the code when the onCheck event called.